# How to get a uinavigation bar back button to return to anthother view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

How would I go about having a UINavigation controller navigate not to the previous view but the view before that. Basically I would like it to jump back 2 places instead of the default one.

This is unconventional I'm sure, but I just need to do it for now.

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:nil
                                     action:nil] autorelease];
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)] autorelease];
```

then create a method `-goBack`

```
-(void)goBack
{
   UIViewController *ctrl = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2];
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you! What if I wanted to specify a particular view controller. Is that possible without breaking the navigation flow?

Answer (score 1):

Add a target to the button you added

then use the following code to go back more than 1 viewController

```
//Get the view controller that is 2 step behind
UIViewController *controller = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:nav.viewControllers.count - 2];

//Go to that controller
[nav popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(youractonEvent:] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to depend on array's index then you can do some thing like below :

```
MyController * aMyController = nil ;
for (int i=0; i<[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count]; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i]);
    if ([[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[MyController class]]) 
    {
        aMyController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:i];      
    }
}           
[self.navigationController popToViewController:aMyController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have three view controllers in NavigationController  and currently you are viewing 3rd view controller and if you want to jump to 1st viewcontroller.

Try this. This will navigate you twice back.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Set appropriate value instead of 0 in your case.