# Storyboard and back button in the uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

When I hit the back button on certain screens I want to pop more than 1 view in some cases back to the root view, programatically if i was hard coding this I would just use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

How would I manage to implement this using storyboard? Whether within the storyboard itself or somehow overriding the storyboards default action programatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The back button belongs to the *previous* view controller. So for example if you start with root view controller A and push B and then C:

```
A -> B -> C
```

The back button you see in C's nav bar is, by default, B's back button, and goes back to B. If that isn't what you want, replace the default `backBarButtonItem` with a custom button whose action you set to a method that pops to the root view controller, as you described already.

There are lots of examples on Stack Overflow. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136801/341994

Comment: Thanks, I handled the problem by adding a custom segue